# Constructing class from string variable cause ClassNotFoundException

Tags: php

When I try to construct new class from string variable, then it throw ClassNotFoundException. I've also tried adding class namespace before it's name, but still not working.

```
public function registerCommands(){
    $commandMap = $this->getServer()->getCommandMap();
    $commands = $this->getCommands();
    foreach($commands as $class => $enterName){
        $commandMap->register("command", new $class($enterName));
    }
}
```

Second try

```
public function registerCommands(){
    $commandMap = $this->getServer()->getCommandMap();
    $commands = $this->getCommands();
    foreach($commands as $class => $enterName){
        $class = "\\server\utils\CommandReader\\" . $class;
        $commandMap->register("command", new $class($enterName));
    }
}
```

$class is string

Comment: And what's the value of `$class`?

Comment: $class = "RecallCommand";

Comment: did you include the corresponding php files before constructing the class?

Comment: yes I did, when I replace new $class with new RecallCommand(), it's working